# Commas between interjectional elements

Tags: commas, interjections

If one wanted to say something like

> `no commas`: Hello Pete, how are you?

or

> `commas`: Thanks, Julia, this will be helpful!

would he need commas separating the different elements in the interjection or just the comma separating the interjection from the rest of the sentence/clause?

Comment: Commas, especially in the such cases as this, are more a matter of writing style and not of grammar at all.

Comment: This refers to the vocative comma. See this related thread: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17651/is-it-acceptable-to-drop-the-comma-in-thanks-john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need commas before the interjection (if it is at the end of a sentence); before and after the interjection (if it is in the middle), including names; after, if it is at the beginning of the sentence.

Examples:

Celia, would you take that call? (Interjection at the beginning)
Will you, Aisha, do that assignment for me? (Interjection in the middle)
Yes, Doctor, I will. (Interjection in the middle)
I can, if you like, complete the project for you. (Interjection in the middle)
I can complete the project for you, if you like. (Interjection at the end)
I can do that for you, Alicia. (Interjection in the middle)

You can find more good rules here: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

Comment: What's with these voluntary down votes :)